# Phaser HTML5 Background change with specific score

Tags: html, phaser-framework

Im trying to change the background in a phaser game once the player reaches a score of 50 or any number really, the back is a png. Is this possible?

this is my code:

```
this.backgroundGame = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background');

     if (this.score == 3)
        this.backgroundGame = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background1');
```

But this is surely not working at all, it kind of brings background1 and covers the whole game if I include the if in the update function, and if I include it on the create function it is just ignored. Any advise? Sorry I'm a newbie and still learning. Also English is not my first language so if my question is not clear let me know thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load in preload() method all background do you need.

```
  this.game.load.image('background', 'images/bg1.png');
  this.game.load.image('background2', 'images/bg2.png');
```

Later add to game one sprite like background:

```
this.backgroundSprite = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background');
this.backgroundSprite = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0,'background');
```

And when will be right time:

```
if (this.score == 3)
    this.backgroundSprite.loadTexture('background1');
```

You will have better performance when you not allways add new object to game word.

Answer (score 1):

In create method you have to set both (or many as you want) backgrounds. As in Phaser layers are like in CSS, the original background (the first of them) has to be the last in create:

--- Create:

```
this.background2 = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background1');
this.backgroundOriginal = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background');
```

Then in update, when your condition is true, you have to set alpha = 0 (invisible) to the original background and the layer behind will be visible.

--- Update:

```
if(this.score == 3) {
    this.backgroundOriginal.alpha = 0;
}
```

PD.: My english is not enough good too... pero supongo que el inglés españolizado si lo entiendes bien, ¿no Rafa? ;)

Comment: Gracias Alberto Buenisima idea que bien que alguien por fin me pudo ayudar voy a probar esta funcion hoy GRACIAS!!

Comment: By the way, the correct tag for Phaser.io is: phaser-framework
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework